# Convert array of paths into tree

Tags: php

I'd like to convert an array of path names like

```
$paths = ["foo/bar/lorem", "foo/bar/ipsum", "foo/dolor"];
```

into a tree array. The matching tree array for the above example would be:

```
$tree = [
    [
        "name" => "foo",
        "children" => [
            [
                "name" => "bar",
                "children" => [
                    [
                        "name" => "lorem",
                        "children" => []
                    ],
                    [
                        "name" => "ipsum",
                        "children" => []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                "name" => "dolor",
                "children" => []
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I know, it can't be that hard, but PHPs handling of passing by reference vs passing by value makes me struggle.

Thank you.

Edit: In my opinion, it's not a duplicate, as in the thread mentioned by you, there are given parent ids.

What I did until now:

```
private function buildTree()
{
    $paths = [
        "foo/bar/lorem",
        "foo/bar/ipsum",
        "foo/dolor",
    ];

    $tree = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $parts = explode("/", $path);

        $currentLevel = &$tree;

        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $existingPath = $this->findByName($currentLevel, $part);
            if ($existingPath) {
                $currentLevel = &$existingPath["children"];
            } else {
                $newPart = [
                    "name" => $part,
                    "children" => [],
                ];

                $currentLevel[] = $newPart;
                $currentLevel = &$newPart["children"];
            }
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

private function findByName(&$array, $name) {
    foreach($array as &$item) {
        if (strcmp($item["name"], $name) === 0) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but this gives my just:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
        string(3) "foo"
      ["children"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the requested information.

Answer (score 4):

This did the trick, but just keep downvoting:

```
private function buildTree()
{
    $paths = [
        "foo/bar/lorem",
        "foo/bar/ipsum",
        "foo/dolor",
    ];

    $tree = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $level = &$tree;

        $parts = explode("/", $path);

        foreach($parts as $part) {
            if (!$this->findByName($level, $part)) {
                $level[] = [
                    "name" => $part,
                    "children" => []
                ];
            }

            $level = &$level[count($level)-1]["children"];
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

private function findByName(&$array, $name) {
    foreach($array as &$item) {
        if (strcmp($item["name"], $name) === 0) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: As you know - down votes aren't worth worrying about, but they will react to new posts and vote purely on that.  Very few people will go back and cancel their downvote no matter how much more detail you put on it.

Answer (score 3):

Very similar to what you've got, but using some of the inbuilt function to find the element to add to...

```
function buildTree()
{
    $paths = [
        "foo/bar/lorem",
        "foo/bar/ipsum",
        "foo/dolor",
    ];

    $tree = [];

    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        $parts = explode("/", $path);
        $node = &$tree;
        foreach ( $parts as $level )   {
            $newNode = array_search ($level, array_column($node, "name")??[]);
            if ( $newNode === false ) {
                $newNode = array_push( $node, [ "name" => $level, "children" => []]) -1;
            }
            $node = &$node[$newNode]["children"];
        }
    }

    return $tree;
}

print_r(buildTree());
```

Comment: why you add -1 in this line $newNode = array_push( $node, [ "name" => $level, "children" => []]) -1; ?

Comment: @SWAT10101, `array_push()` returns the new length of the array.  So -1 will give the element number in the array of the item added (as arrays are 0 based).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I showed up late to the game, but here is another solution using a recursive function:

```
<?php
$paths = array("foo/bar/lorem", "foo/bar/ipsum", "foo/dolor");

$test = [];

foreach($paths as $path){
    $splitPath = preg_split('/\//', $path);
    addChild($test, $splitPath);
}

function addChild(&$arr, &$splitPath){
    $parent = array_shift($splitPath);
    //check for $parent in $test array
    $foundParent = 0;
    foreach($arr as &$item){
        if($item['name'] == $parent){
            if(count($splitPath) > 0){addChild($item['children'], $splitPath);}
            $foundParent = 1;
        }
    }
    //if not found, add to array
    if($foundParent == 0){
        $arr[] = array('name' => $parent,'children' => []);
        if(count($splitPath) > 0){addChild($arr[count($arr)-1]['children'], $splitPath);}
    }
}

print_r($test);

?>
```